# Safely Marking Begin/End Of Packet for TCP / UDP transmission

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, udp, packet

I am writing a client/server based application that works over local network, to exchange data between client and server, I have created a very simple `NetworkCommand` object that is converted to `byte[]` and the send with `TCP` or `UDP`.

The problem is marking the `end-of-packed` properly,

right now i have used `byte[] {0, 0, 0}`  and end of packet marker, but that is seemed to be repeated too many times in the complete packet itself.

So, How do i safely mark the **`end-of-packet`** ?

NetworkCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Cybotech.Common
{
    public enum CommandType
        {
            NeedIP = 1,
            IPData = 2,
        }

    public class NetworkCommand
    {
        public NetworkCommand(CommandType type, byte[] data)
        {
            Command = type;
            Data = data;
        }

        public int Length
        {
            get { return Data.Length; }
        }

        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        public CommandType Command { get; set; }

        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            //write the command type
            byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes((int) Command);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            //append the length of the data
            data = BitConverter.GetBytes(Length);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            //write the data
            stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);

            //end of packer marker
            data = new byte[] {0, 0, 0};
            stream.Write(data, 0, 3);

            data = stream.ToArray();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
            return data;

        }

        public static NetworkCommand CreateNetworkCommand(byte[] bytes)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            CommandType type = (CommandType) reader.ReadInt32();
            int length = reader.ReadInt32();
            byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(length);
            byte[] endMarker = reader.ReadBytes(3);

            NetworkCommand cmd = new NetworkCommand(type, data);
            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
            return cmd;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy is to *begin* the packet with, say, a 4-byte number that represents the packet size, and follow it with the appropriate number of payload data bytes.  Then you know exactly how much data you need to read on the receiving end.

TCP is a reliable protocol, so you needn't be too concerned about synchronization.  On the other hand, it's stream-oriented, and since you're using a packet-based application layer you may find it easier to use UDP, which is message-oriented.

If you use UDP, you can use a 4-byte length, followed by an arbitrary "start" character (like `[`), then the payload, and finally a "stop" character (like `]`).  If you read a packet that doesn't end with the stop character you can discard it, and continue discarding data through the next stop character.  But then you'll need a way to ask the sender to retransmit the lost data.

A good protocol leverages the underlying layers, so you won't need to duplicate their features.

Comment: well either way, i have to mark a begin header or end marker?